# List all the operator families associated with a schema and all the operators within an operator family?

Tags: postgresql

G'day,

How can you select/list all the operator families associated with a database/schema and list all the operations within an operation family in postgreSQL (8.3 if it matters).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator families in a schema:

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_opfamily opf JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = opf.opfnamespace
WHERE n.nspname = 'something';
```

Getting all the operators within an operator family is more tricky, because an operator families contains some operators directly and some through operator classes that in contains.  To get the former, join `pg_opfamily` with `pg_amop`, to get the latter, join `pg_opfamily` with `pg_opclass`, and then in both cases against `pg_operator`.  It's questionable how useful this information will be, though, because in order to assess the usability of an operator family for query planning and optimization, you also need information about access methods, data types, and a few other things.

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-psql.html): Use it from within the psql command prompt

> ```
> \do [ pattern ]
> ```
>
> Lists available operators with their operand and return types. If
>   pattern is specified, only operators
>   whose names match the pattern are
>   listed.

Comment: If you need the SQL to select this, run psql with the `-E` option

Comment: That just lists the operators, not the operator families though.